# freeswitch sip trunk not receiving inbound calls

Tags: linux, asterisk, freeswitch, inbound, fusionpbx

my sip trunk provider has given me a user name sip123456 when I configure that siip trunk as a gateway, I can make calls out no problem but I cannot receive any inbound calls! Now I did a lot of investigation and I found out that the user name has to be set as the telephone number for inbound calls to work, is there any other ways to overcome that issue in freeswitch, as my SIP trunk provider is unwilling to change the user name to the matching telephone number?

For information I am unable to provide a log as the call does not even reach freeswitch, my provider does not wish to provide a trace, also this issue happens in Asterisk, and Fusionpbx too! Now to make sure that my findings were correct, I used a different provider with another client, which uses telephone number as the user name, and my configuration works on both incoming and outgoing. I'm sure you would say to dump the other SIP provider but my client wants to find a solution hence I am posting this question...

My sincere apologies for being unable to provide further information such as trace logs etc, but has anyone faced the same issue, if yes what other work around have you used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** *programming question* that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to Call Detail Records and find which variable contains the number you called. You would then use that variable for the inbound routes. You can change a setting in Default Settings
Category: dialplan
Subcategory: destination
Type: text
Value: ${sip_to_user}
In this example I used sip_to_user your carrier may send the number that was dialed in that variable or they could send it another way. Either way find your phone number and use the correct variable name. If this setting doesn't exist then add it. Click on the 'Reload' button to make the changes take effect. Go to Dialplan -> Destinations and re-save your inbound destinations and it will rewrite the inbound routes for you with the new variable.

Best Regards, Mark J Crane - FusionPBX Creator